# Obtaining MinGW installation with GCC 4.1.1

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw

I need to use the GCC compiler version 4.1.1 on Windows, from a MingGW distribution if possible.

I've been looking for a way to install an older version with the mingw-get installer but I don't find any option to select a specific version. Nevertheless, the official Sourceforge repository doesn't seem to contain the files for this version (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version4/)

After searching in alternative distributions like Nuwen or TDM-GCC I haven't found a release including GCC 4.1.1.

My question is, is there any place to obtain a MinGW with GCC 4.1.1, or is there another way to obtain this toolchain?

Thanks.

Comment: $Hoober:Why gcc4.1.1?

Comment: @Charles0429 for compatibility reasons with and old version of another software (Matlab). Long story short: the linux version of this software is officially compatible with GCC 4.1.1, and I need to replicate the compiler environment in Windows

Comment: @JoachimPileborg do you mean compiling GCC or MinGW? I haven't found a clear explanation on how to do the later one, and I don't know if I can mix an old GCC compiler with a newer version of MinGW

Comment: I mean GCC. Download MinGW with a current up-to-date version of GCC already, and then download the source of the wanted version of GCC and compile it. The "new" version you compile will have its version as a prefix, so to later use it you use e.g. the command `gcc-4.1.1`.

Comment: If 4.1.2 is close enough, you can get a TDM build here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/TDM-GCC%20Old%20Releases/4.1.2-tdm-3/

Comment: Why not just run any newer gcc with a `-std=` flag (e.g. `-std=c89` or `-std=gnu90`) to select the compatibility you need?